# Insert form values in sql database in MVC 4

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

My MVC 4 application requires me to store the textbox values of my form in an SQL database. I have created the stored procedure for insertion of the record. However, the `[HttpPost]` function that is to be written in the controller is unclear to me..

Can anyone please suggest a solution??

Answer (score 0):

This page: [How To Call a Parameterized Stored Procedure by Using ADO.NET and Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310070) contains some sample code that will help you.